# VTK different objects in actor with different opacities

Tags: python, c++, vtk

I am using the python vtk wrapper and what I have learnt so far, vtk renders different objects of the same actor with the same opacity value. I need some way so that I can set opacities of different objects of the same actor.

Comment: Can you share some code ? How do you add several geometry in the same actor ? I think this not intended

Comment: Actually the python vtk wrapper allows us to pass a list of coordinates and dimentions to create a list of geometrical figures. For example I can create 10 spheres with different centres and different radii in the same actor. But there is no way to change the opacity value of any of the individual spheres.

Answer (score 0):

[From this doc](https://kitware.github.io/vtk-examples/site/VTKBook/03Chapter3/#310-putting-it-all-together) an actor is intendend to handle one geometry and its associated properties, so you cannot set different opacities on one actor.
You will need to create one actor per object you want to control.

A workaround if you really need only one actor, is to associate data to your geometry and then use the vtkMapper ability to map data into a color per vertex, using [color maps and lookuptable](https://kitware.github.io/vtk-examples/site/VTKBook/06Chapter6/#mapper-design)